# Problema con resolución de ejercicio Javascript

Tags: javascript

no entiendo muy bien el ejercicio de Javascript que os muestro a continuación:

---

Crea un archivo llamando if-statement.js.

En ese archivo, declara una variabe llamada fruit.

Haz la variable fruit referenciar al valor orange, del tipo String.

Luego utiliza console.log() para imprimir a la terminal "The fruit name

has more than five characters." si el length de la variable fruit es

mayor
  a cinco. Imprime "The fruit name has five characters or less." de lo

contrario.

---

Yo he hecho esto:

---

```
var fruit = 6;

if (fruit > 5) {
    console.log("The fruit name has more than five characters.");
} else {
    console.log("The fruit name has five characters or less.");
}
```

---

Pero no estoy seguro de si es así o si tengo que pasar de alguna manera el string 'orange' a números.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Para conocer el tamaño de un string, usa su propiedad length.
if (fruit.length>5)... etc

Comment: eso no es JavaScript, o estas manejando Java o es Typescript

Comment: El planteamiento del problema no es claro, parece inconcluso... pero lo que parece pedir es que crees una variable `fruit` y que le des un valor de cadena y que luego en un condicional imprimas un mensaje u otro según  el **tamaño** de ese cadena.

Answer (score 2):

Si pones algo como esto:

```
var food = "manzana"
```

Y quieres saber su tamaño debes usar el método length como lo dijo Arnau Castellví

```
var tam = food.length;//te da 7
```

Ya casi tienes el código.

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera amigo.

```
//declaramos la variable fruit
var fruit;
//asignamos el valor orange
fruit = "orange";
//Si su tamaño es mayor:
if(fruit.length > 5){
  console.log('The fruit namehas more than five characters.');
} else {
  console.log('The fruit name has five characters or less.')
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo pude solucionar con vuestra ayuda.

Comment: que bueno que haya servido :D si puedes darle el check como resuelto estaria tambien agredecido